# DISCORD PY: How to store user input into a variable?

Tags: discord, discord.py

I am currently creating a simple login system for my discord server and im trying to find a way to store the user input into a variable and using it for a database. I currently want the input of [https://steamcommunity.com/id/] in the variable.

````
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('!login'):
        channel = message.channel
        embed = discord.Embed(color=discord.Color.red())
        embed.set_author(name='{0.user}'.format(client), icon_url='https://scontent.fsyd1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.15752-9/119154591_373692013645493_2520568812144261390_n.png?_nc_cat=100&ccb=2&_nc_sid=ae9488&_nc_ohc=qee8e9Q3a0sAX9_z2Nj&_nc_ht=scontent.fsyd1-1.fna&oh=ffeafaaa09f2bb802afce08030c41f08&oe=60394D0B')
        embed.add_field(name='WELCOME TO LINKED.GG', value='Looking forward to seeing you in queue!', inline=False)
        embed.add_field(name='Link your STEAM account to the bot:',
                        value='Reply to this bots message: \n `!login <steam profile url>`', inline=False)
        embed.add_field(name='Please read over the rules:',
                        value='<#804911670698442815>', inline=False)
        embed.add_field(name='Join our discord server', value='[Click to join discord](https://discord.gg/2dKCUAzceN)', inline=True)
        await channel.send(embed=embed)

        def check(m):
            return m.content.startswith('https://steamcommunity.com/id/') and m.channel == channel

        msg = await client.wait_for('message', check=check)
        print(msg)
        await channel.send('Connected {.author}!'.format(msg))
    await client.process_commands(message)```
````

Comment: Avoid embedding functions inside of functions. You should be able to answer your own question based off of the code. To assign a value to a variable name, `test = some_expression`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's better by using a command instead of an `on_message` then you can pass an argument with the logging command. Ill leave it up to you to get your database sorted out, and searching if an account was already created.

Below is a simple example of passing a "username" argument through the command, the username would then be stored within the `username` variable.

```
@client.command()
async def login(ctx, *, username=None):
    if username == None:
        await ctx.send(f'{ctx.author.mention}, please enter your username to log in!')
        return
    await ctx.send(f'Logged in as {username}! Welcome back.')
```